# How to load image from a portable device (smartphone)

Tags: shell, delphi, load, portability

I'm using IShellFolder interface to get a list of files/folders.

From this list I want to load an image file (let's say  a "someimage.bmp"  file) into TBitmap. It's no problem when I get the list of files from a local harddrive, but I need to load an image from a portable device. For example, I have Sony Xperia C, and I get a list of images from DCIM folder,

```
var
  pShell, Desktop: IShellFolder;
  FolderPIDL, ItemPIDL: PITEMIDLIST;
  PMalloc: IMalloc;
   xperia: string;
  EnumIDList: IEnumIDList;
  pceltFetched: ULONG;
  FileExt:String;
begin



 try
    SHGetDesktopFolder(Desktop);
    xperia:= '::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_0fce&pid_51a3&mi_00#7&12ccae3c&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}';
    GetPIDLFromPath(handle, xperia, FolderPIDL);

    SHGetMalloc(PMalloc);
Desktop.BindToObject(FolderPIDL, nil, IID_IShellFolder, Pointer(pShell));

pShell.EnumObjects(0,SHCONTF_FOLDERS or SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS or SHCONTF_STORAGE, EnumIDList);
while EnumIDList.Next(1,ItemPIDL, pceltFetched) = S_ok do
begin
  pceltFetched := 0;
  FileExt:= GetExtension(pShell, ItemPIDL);
   Memo1.Lines.Add(FileExt);
      if FileExt = '.jpg' then begin
        ///  Creating TBitmap
        ///
        ///  How to LOAD ????
        ///
        ///
        ///
        ///
      end

    end;
  finally
    pMalloc._Release;
    pMalloc := nil;
  end;
```

But the path to each image looks like this:

::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\?\usb#vid_0fce&pid_51a3&mi_00#7&12ccae3c&0&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\SID-{10001,65537,16003366912}{000007DC-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}{000015DC-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}{000015E0-0001-0001-0000-000000000000}

I can convert this path  into: My Computer\Xperia C\DCIM\100ANDRO\DSC_0004.JPG  but TBitmap.LoadFomFile() won't understand any of the paths of course. 
I thought maybe I needed to copy those images to some temporary folder and then do all the staff, but it will be too slow and really not a good option.

Another way would be using IExtractImage but, I really need to know if there is another way to deal with files (not only images) stored inside portable devices.

If someone knows how to do this, please help me. Thanks.